# Iterating nested associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to iterate a nested associative array.
After every iteration I also get an `undefined` value:

```
testarr = [];

testarr["key1"] = [];
testarr["key2"] = [];

testarr["key1"].push("val1");
testarr["key1"].push("val2");
testarr["key1"].push("val3");

testarr["key2"].push("val4");
testarr["key2"].push("val5");
testarr["key2"].push("val6");

for (var key in testarr) {
  console.log("---" + key + "---")
  for (var key2 in key) {
    console.log(testarr[key][key2])
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
---key1---
val1
val2
val3
undefined
---key2---
val4
val5
val6
undefined
```

Where does it come from?

Comment: It is not recommended to use *for..in* to iterate over an array as the order in which properties are returned may not be what you expect and you may find enumerable properties that aren't own properties. Also, while Arrays are Objects, they are expected to be used with numeric keys, not alphabetic. An Object seems more appropriate in this case for *testarr*.

Comment: @RobG Is this an array or an object?

Comment: @John— *testarr* is an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second for loop, you are iterating over "key", which is the index, instead of "testarr[key]".

```
for (var key in testarr) {
    console.log("---" + key + "---")
    for (var key2 in testarr[key]) {
        console.log(testarr[key][key2])
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid `for.in` loops with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this is

```
Object.keys(testarr).forEach( k => {console.log("---" + k + "---");
Object.keys(testarr[k]).forEach( i => console.log(testarr[k][i]))});
```

Comment: There is no need to use *Object.keys* on the members of *testarr*, you can use *forEach* directly on them as they have numeric indexes, so `Object.keys(testarr).forEach(function(arr){arr.forEach(...)})`.

Comment: Yes you are right.. + for that. I just couldn't slow down :)  Then it would be somewhat shorter like `Object.keys(testarr).forEach( k => {console.log("---" + k + "---");
testarr[k].forEach( i => console.log(i))});`